# Node.js long process ran twice

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js restful API built in express.js framework. It is usually hosted by pm2.

One of the services has very long process. When front end called the service, the process started up. Since there is an error in database, the process won't be done properly and the error would be caught. However, before the process reached the error, another exactly same process started with same parameters. So in the meantime, two processes were both running while one was ahead of the other. After a long time, the first process reached error point and returned error. Then the second one returned exactly the same thing.

I checked front end Network and noticed there was actually only one request sent. Where did the second request come from?

**Edit 1:**

The whole process is: **first process sends query to db -> long time wait -> second process starts up -> second process sends query to db -> long time wait -> first process receives db response -> long time wait -> second process receives db response**

**Edit 2:**

The code of the service is as follow:

```
import { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import * as multer from "multer";
import * as fs from "fs";
import { Readable, Duplex } from "stream";
import * as uid from "uid";
import { Client } from "pg";
import * as gdal from "gdal";
import * as csv from "csv";

import { SuccessPayload, ErrorPayload } from "../helpers/response";
import { postgresQuery } from "../helpers/database";
import Config from "../config";

export default class ShapefileRoute {
    constructor(app: Express) {

        // Upload a shapefile
        /**
          * @swagger
          * /shapefile:
          *   post:
          *     description: Returns the homepage
          *     responses:
          *       200:
          */
        app.post("/shapefile", (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function): void => {

            // Create instance of multer
            const multerInstance = multer().array("files");

            multerInstance(req, res, (err: Error) => {
                if (err) {
                    let payload: ErrorPayload = {
                        code: 4004,
                        errorMessage: "Multer upload file error.",
                        errorDetail: err.message,
                        hints: "Check error detail"
                    };

                    req.reservePayload = payload;

                    next();

                    return;
                }
                // Extract files
                let files: any = req.files;

                // Extract body
                let body: any = JSON.parse(req.body.filesInfo);

                // Other params
                let writeFilePromises: Promise<any>[] = [];

                let copyFilePromises: Promise<any>[] = [];

                let rootDirectory: string = Config.uploadRoot;

                let outputId: string = uid(4);

                // Reset index of those files
                let namesIndex: string[] = [];
                files.forEach((item: Express.Multer.File, index: number) => {
                    if(item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "csv" || item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "txt" || item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "shp") {
                        namesIndex.push(item.originalname);
                    }
                })

                // Process and write all files to disk
                files.forEach((item: Express.Multer.File, outterIndex: number) => {
                    if(item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "csv" || item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "txt") {
                        namesIndex.forEach((indexItem, index) => {
                            if(indexItem === item.originalname) {
                                ShapefileRoute.csv(item, index, writeFilePromises, body, rootDirectory, outputId,);
                            }
                        })
                    } else if (item.originalname.split(".")[1] === "shp") {
                        namesIndex.forEach((indexItem, index) => {
                            if(indexItem === item.originalname) {
                                ShapefileRoute.shp(item, index, writeFilePromises, body, rootDirectory, outputId,);
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        ShapefileRoute.shp(item, outterIndex, writeFilePromises, body, rootDirectory, outputId,);
                    }
                })

                // Copy files from disk to database
                ShapefileRoute.copyFiles(req, res, next, writeFilePromises, copyFilePromises, req.reserveSuperPg, () => {
                    ShapefileRoute.loadFiles(req, res, next, copyFilePromises, body, outputId)
                });


            })
        });
    }

    // Process csv file
    static csv(file: Express.Multer.File, index: number, writeFilePromises: Promise<any>[], body: any, rootDirectory: string, outputId: string) {

        // Streaming file to pivotcsv
        writeFilePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Get specification from body
            let delimiter: string;
            let spec: any;
            let lrsColumns: string[] = [null, null, null, null, null, null];
            body.layers.forEach((jsonItem, i) => {
                if (jsonItem.name === file.originalname.split(".")[0]) {
                    delimiter = jsonItem.file_spec.delimiter;
                    spec = jsonItem
                    jsonItem.lrs_cols.forEach((lrsCol) => {
                        switch(lrsCol.lrs_type){
                            case "rec_id":
                            lrsColumns[0] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                            case "route_id":
                            lrsColumns[1] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                            case "f_meas":
                            lrsColumns[2] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                            case "t_meas":
                            lrsColumns[3] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                            case "b_date":
                            lrsColumns[4] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                            case "e_date":
                            lrsColumns[5] = lrsCol.name;
                            break;
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            // Pivot csv file
            ShapefileRoute.pivotCsv(file.buffer, `${rootDirectory}/${outputId}_${index}`, index, delimiter, outputId, lrsColumns, (path) => {
                console.log("got pivotCsv result");
                spec.order = index;
                resolve({
                    path: path,
                    spec: spec
                });
            }, reject);
        }));
    }

    // Process shapefile
    static shp(file: Express.Multer.File, index: number, writeFilePromises: Promise<any>[], body: any, rootDirectory: string, outputId: string) {

        // Write file to disk and then call shp2csv to gennerate csv
        writeFilePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // Write shpefile to disk
            fs.writeFile(`${rootDirectory}/shps/${file.originalname}`, file.buffer, (err) => {

                // If it is .shp file, resolve it's path and spec
                if(file.originalname.split(".")[1] === "shp") {
                    // Find spec of the shapefile from body
                    body.layers.forEach((jsonItem, i) => {
                        if (jsonItem.name === file.originalname.split(".")[0]) {
                            let recordColumn: string = null;
                            let routeIdColumn: string = null;
                            jsonItem.lrs_cols.forEach((lrsLayer) => {
                                if (lrsLayer.lrs_type === "rec_id") {
                                    recordColumn = lrsLayer.name;
                                }
                                if (lrsLayer.lrs_type === "route_id") {
                                    routeIdColumn = lrsLayer.name;
                                }
                            })

                            // Transfer shp to csv
                            ShapefileRoute.shp2csv(`${rootDirectory}/shps/${file.originalname}`, `${rootDirectory}/${outputId}_${index}`, index, outputId, recordColumn, routeIdColumn, (path, srs) => {

                                // Add coordinate system, geom column and index of this file to spec
                                jsonItem.file_spec.proj4 = srs;
                                jsonItem.file_spec.geom_col = "geom";
                                jsonItem.order = index;

                                // Return path and spec
                                resolve({
                                    path: path,
                                    spec: jsonItem
                                })
                            }, (err) => {
                                reject;
                            })
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            })
        }));
    }

    // Copy files to database
    static copyFiles(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function, writeFilePromises: Promise<any>[], copyFilePromises: Promise<any>[], client: Client, callback: () => void) {
        // Take all files generated by writefile processes
        Promise.all(writeFilePromises)
        .then((results) => {

            // Remove null results. They are from .dbf .shx etc of shapefile.
            const files: any = results.filter(arr => arr);

            // Create promise array. This will be triggered after all files are written to database.
            files.forEach((file) => {
                copyFilePromises.push(new Promise((copyResolve, copyReject) => {
                    let query: string = `copy lbo.lbo_temp from '${file.path}' WITH NULL AS 'null';`;

                    // Create super user call
                    postgresQuery(client, query, (data) => {
                        copyResolve(file.spec);
                    }, copyReject);
                }));
            });

            // Trigger upload query
            callback()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Response as error if any file generating is wrong
            let payload: ErrorPayload = {
                code: 4004,
                errorMessage: "Something wrong when processing csv and/or shapefile.",
                errorDetail: err.message,
                hints: "Check error detail"
            };

            req.reservePayload = payload;

            next();

        })
    }


    // Load layers in database
    static loadFiles(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function, copyFilePromises: Promise<any>[], body: any, outputId: string) {

        Promise.all(copyFilePromises)
        .then((results) => {

            // Resort all results by the order assigned when creating files
            results.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.order - b.order;
            });
            results.forEach((result) => {
                delete result.order;
            });

            // Create JSON for load layer database request
            let taskJson = body;
            taskJson.layers = results;
            let query: string = `select lbo.load_layers2(p_session_id := '${outputId}', p_layers := '${JSON.stringify(taskJson)}'::json)`;

            postgresQuery(req.reservePg, query, (data) => {
                // Get result
                let result = data.rows[0].load_layers2.result;

                // Return 4003 error if no result
                if (!result) {
                    let payload: ErrorPayload = {
                        code: 4003,
                        errorMessage: "Load layers error.",
                        errorDetail: data.rows[0].load_layers2.error ? data.rows[0].load_layers2.error.message : "Load layers returns no result.",
                        hints: "Check error detail"
                    };

                    req.reservePayload = payload;

                    next();

                    return;
                }
                let payload: SuccessPayload = {
                    type: "string",
                    content: "Upload files done."
                };

                req.reservePayload = payload;

                next();
            }, (err) => {
                req.reservePayload = err;

                next();
            });

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Response as error if any file generating is wrong
            let payload: ErrorPayload = {
                code: 4004,
                errorMessage: "Something wrong when copy files to database.",
                errorDetail: err,
                hints: "Check error detail"
            };

            req.reservePayload = payload;

            next();
        })

    }

    // Pivot csv process. Write output csv to disk and return path of the file.
    static pivotCsv(buffer: Buffer, outputPath: string, inputIndex: number, delimiter: string, outputId: string, lrsColumns: string[], callback: (path: string) => void, errCallback: (err: Error) => void) {

        let inputStream: Duplex = new Duplex();

        // Define output stream
        let output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath, {flags: "a"});
        // Callback when output stream is done
        output.on("finish", () => {
            console.log("output stream finish");
            callback(outputPath);
        });

        // Define parser stream
        let parser = csv.parse({
            delimiter: delimiter
        });
        // Close output stream when parser stream is end
        parser.on("end", () => {
            console.log("parser stream end");
            output.end();
        });
        // Write data when a chunck is parsed
        let header = [null, null, null, null, null, null];
        let attributesHeader = [];
        let i = 0;
        let datumIndex: boolean = true;
        parser.on("data", (chunk) => {
            console.log("parser received on chunck: ", i);
            if (datumIndex) {
                chunk.forEach((datum, index) => {
                    if (lrsColumns.includes(datum)) {
                        header[lrsColumns.indexOf(datum)] = index;
                    } else {
                        attributesHeader.push({
                            name: datum,
                            index: index
                        })
                    }
                });
                datumIndex = false;
            } else {
                i ++;
                // let layer_id = ;
                let rec_id = header[0] ? chunk[header[0]] : i;
                let route_id = header[1] ? chunk[header[1]] : null;
                let f_meas = header[2] ? chunk[header[2]] : null;
                let t_meas = header[3] ? chunk[header[3]] : null;
                let b_date = header[4] ? chunk[header[4]] : null;
                let e_date = header[5] ? chunk[header[5]] : null;

                let attributes = {};

                attributesHeader.forEach((attribute) => {
                    attributes[attribute.name] = chunk[attribute.index];
                });

                let attributesOrdered = {};
                Object.keys(attributes).sort().forEach((key) => {
                    attributesOrdered[key] = attributes[key];
                });

                let outputData = `${outputId}\t${inputIndex}\t${rec_id}\t${route_id}\tnull\t${f_meas}\t${t_meas}\t${b_date}\t${e_date}\tnull\t${JSON.stringify(attributesOrdered)}\n`;

                output.write(outputData);
            }
        });



        inputStream.push(buffer);
        inputStream.push(null);
        inputStream.pipe(parser);
    }

    // Write shp and transfer to database format. Return file path and projection.
    static shp2csv(inputPath: string, outputPath: string, i: number, ouputId: string, recordColumn: string, routeIdColumn: string, callback: (path: string, prj: string) => void, errCallback: (err: Error) => void) {
        let dataset = gdal.open(inputPath);
        let layercount = dataset.layers.count();
        let layer = dataset.layers.get(0);
        let output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath, {flags: "a"});
        output.on("finish", () => {
            callback(outputPath, layer.srs.toProj4());
        });
        layer.features.forEach((feature, featureId) => {
            let geom;
            let recordId: number = null;
            let routeId: string = null;
            try {
                let geomWKB = feature.getGeometry().toWKB();
                let geomWKBString = geomWKB.toString("hex");
                geom = geomWKBString;
                if (recordColumn) {
                    recordId = feature.fields.get(recordColumn);
                }
                if (routeIdColumn) {
                    routeId = feature.fields.get(routeIdColumn);
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            let attributes = {};

            let attributesOrdered = {};

            feature.fields.forEach((value, field) => {
                if (field != recordColumn && field != routeIdColumn) {
                    attributes[field] = value;
                }
            });

            Object.keys(attributes).sort().forEach((key) => {
                attributesOrdered[key] = attributes[key];
            });
            output.write(`${ouputId}\t${i.toString()}\t${recordId ? recordId : (featureId + 1).toString()}\t${routeId}\tnull\tnull\tnull\tnull\tnull\t${geom}\t${JSON.stringify(attributesOrdered)}\n`);
        });
        output.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: I rather doubt we can help you without seeing the relevant code.  If indeed, only one network request was sent, then you have a bug in  your code that is starting the second process.  If there is no bug in your code, then two network requests were sent.  It pretty much has to be one or the other, but without any information specific to your code and configuration, there's nothing we could do here but make wild guesses.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for the response! I felt the same way at first. After some research and debug, I am pretty sure my code doesn't have a bug. One evidence is that the running twice issue doesn't happen every time. If it is a code issue, the problem should happen every time right? The code of this service is too long to post here. And I am 80% sure this issue is not code related. I asked this question just to get some idea about what could cause the problem.

Comment: No, not correct that all bugs happen 100% of the time.  Many bugs are intermittent or timing-related or race-condition related.  There's either a coding bug or you are receiving two network requests.  It's one or the other.  You told us there are not two network requests (which I'm not entirely sure I believe).  What else can it possibly be?  You should be able to instrument your code with `console.log()` statements to find out exactly what is happening.

Comment: Nothing we can do here with the level of information you've provided.  You told us a black box is not working correctly, but you won't show us anything in the black box.

Comment: Got it. I agree with you. The information I provided is not enough. Do you know what's the best way to identify a request? I think I should provide some information of the request like sender, send time and so on. Note the server is under express.js platform.

Comment: Then put a `console.log()` into the express request handler that runs this.  You can add the date/time to it.  If you have a cookie that identifies the user, you can add that to the log statement too.  You could also add the IP address of the source of the request.

Comment: From the help center: ***Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.***

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your advice! Regarding the console.log(), I think you want to identify the step where the second process starts up right? It happens while the first process is waiting for database's response. I edit my question with a explanation of the whole thing.

Comment: Do you ever make more than one `ShapefileRoute` instance?  If you do, then you will have duplicate route handlers and will process every event more than once.

Comment: No, only one instance. I make the instance when start the server.

Comment: Where in the code do you start another process?

Comment: Very beginning of the service. Specifically **const multerInstance = multer().array("files");**

Comment: Where do you get the idea that `multer()` creates a new process?  The multer I know is middleware that helps you process files uploaded with incoming requests.  I'm not aware of any option for it to start another process.  It does its work asynchronously by reading the incoming stream.

Comment: Sorry I confused you. The multer() does not start the process. It is the beginning of the process. I don't know which command triggers the service. It is like node.js server receives another request. I guess the request is not come from inside the service

Comment: I guess I have no idea what you're asking any more.  Not sure how to help further.

Comment: @jfriend00 You already helped me a lot. I really appreciate it. I realized it is not about the particular service. The problem happened to all services. For example, it even happens to **setTimeout(() => {res.send("hello")}, 150000);** Once a service doesn't response in 2 minutes (I figured it out with several experiments and it is exactly 2 minutes) and the browser is still open, the service will be called another time. If the browser is closed, the second call won't happen. I am doing more research on it.

Comment: The browser retries if it doesn't get a response.  Two minutes is too long to ask the browser to wait for a response.  You may need to have the browser send it's request, have your server respond, then have the client make a different request some time later to get the final result.  Or use a webSocket or socket.io connection to communicate back the eventual result.

Comment: Is there some way to configure it?

Comment: You can't control the browser's timeout from your server.  Two minutes is just too long to ask it to wait.  You need a different design that responds sooner and then communicates back the eventual result later when it's ready.  Either client polling or server push with webSocket/socket.io.

Comment: I use socket for my long processes. Since this is a new developed service, I haven't deployed socket.io to it yet. What I usually do is let the service respond instantly and then use socket.io to deliver result/error. Is this a proper way?

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser retries some requests if the server doesn't send a response and the browser hits its timeout value.  Each browser may be configured with its own timeout, but 2 minutes sounds like it's probably the browser timeout.

You can't control the browser's timeout from your server. Two minutes is just too long to ask it to wait. You need a different design that responds sooner and then communicates back the eventual result later when it's ready. Either client polling or server push with webSocket/socket.io.

For client polling, you could have the server respond immediately from your first request and return back a token (some unique string).  Then, the client can ask the server for the response for that token every minute until the server eventually has the response.  If the server doesn't yet have the response, it just immediately returns back a code that means no response yet.  If so, the client sets a timer and tries again in a minute, sending the token each time so the server knows which request it is asking about.

For server push, the client creates a persistent webSocket or socket.io connection to the server.  When the client makes it's long running request, the server just immediately returns the same type of token described above.  Then, when the server is done with the request, it sends the token and the final data over the socket.io connection.  The client is listening for incoming messages on that socket.io connection and will receive the final response there.